# Retrieving the user name and email id from Facebook into my android app

Tags: android

I am trying to get the user details like username and email id from the Facebook account who Log in to my android app through Facebook... First i created the code in which user can log in into my app through Facebook...that code i have given below...it is working correctly....but what i have to do to get user details from Facebook

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private MainFragment mainFragment;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content,   mainFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;


public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private LoginButton authButton;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception              exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(),callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,   Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
       // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),     ContentSliderActivity.class));
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please any one its urgent...thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get user details from facebook first it will required **public_profile** permission from user and once user allow you can get it

To get User Details you can user below method.once the session is valid after successfully logged in with user permissions you can get user details by using that session.

```
private void getUserDetails(final Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                String id = user.getId();
                                String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                String lastName = user.getLastName();
                                String name = user.getName();
//**Here you can get details of the user. show toast or display from here
                            }
                        }
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            Log.e("ERROR", response.getError()
                                    .getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Where to apply in your fragment ?. `onSessionStateChange` method of `MainFragment`

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            // Call getUserDetails if session is valid and user successfully
            // logged in
            getUserDetails(session);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }
```

MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private LoginButton authButton;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home1, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            // Call getUserDetails if session is valid and user successfully
            // logged in
            getUserDetails(session);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private void getUserDetails(final Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                String id = user.getId();
                                String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                String lastName = user.getLastName();
                                String name = user.getName();
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getActivity(),
                                        "Name : " + name + " ID  : " + id
                                                + " First name : " + firstName
                                                + " Last Name : " + lastName,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            Log.e("ERROR", response.getError()
                                    .getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: you can put that method in MainFragment and call that method in onSessionStateChange  method

Comment: The app got Login through Facebook....but how i will get to know that details got extracted ....can i add toast???

Comment: @manjugkk you can check the udpated answer with MainFragment and toast.

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 toast.show();............I am using this toast but it is showing error...what is wrong in that

Comment: last thing this is only ....tell me how to toast...and syntax...remaining all thing is done...please

Comment: check the updated answer ... i have placed Whole code with fragment... and you can also check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: Toast is not coming....see my app structure is coming like this...when i run the project i will get page with button(login with Facebook) and then if i click that one it is going to page displaying that some data will stored in testapp that is it...after clicking the ok button it will get exited ....

Answer (score 0):

This May Work...

```
public class FacebookInfo extends Activity {
...
String get_id, get_name, get_gender, get_email, get_birthday, get_locale, get_location;

private Session.StatusCallback fbStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

// the Response from the Api is stored in response variable 

               log.i("Response is"+response);

                    if (response != null) {
                        // do something with <response> now
                        try{
                            get_id = user.getId();
                            get_name = user.getName();
                            get_gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
                            get_email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
                            get_birthday = user.getBirthday();
                            get_locale = (String) user.getProperty("locale");
                            get_location = user.getLocation().toString();   

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, user.getId() + "; " +  
                            user.getName() + "; " +
                            (String) user.getProperty("gender") + "; " +        
                            (String) user.getProperty("email") + "; " +
                            user.getBirthday()+ "; " +
                            (String) user.getProperty("locale") + "; " +
                            user.getLocation());
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception e");
                         }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
...
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fbinfo);
    try {
        openActiveSession(this, true, fbStatusCallback, Arrays.asList(
                new String[] { "email",  "user_location", "user_birthday",
 "user_likes", "publish_actions" }), savedInstanceState);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  private  Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI,
 StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity).
setPermissions(permissions).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.
SSO_WITH_FALLBACK).setCallback(callback).
setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + session);
    if (session == null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, fbStatusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) || allowLoginUI) {
            session.openForRead(openRequest);
            return session;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Comment: This large block of code _might_ work, but it's missing any explanation of _why_ or _how_ it solves the problem.

Comment: and To Manage the Session for Log out.. store the access token using Shared Prefs for simple Methods or do as i've done in onCreate() method